# What does fill_value mean in the context of stats.spearmanr results

Tags: python, scipy

I am getting the following result when running stats.spearmanr on two columns

```
SpearmanrResult(correlation=-0.3921951172279409, pvalue=masked_array(data=0.,
             mask=False,
       fill_value=1e+20))
```

I had added the nan_policy='omit' to ignore nan values in either of my columns.

I don't understand what fill_value means in this context

Comment: 1 followed by 20 numbers for example, 1000 is 1e3

Comment: I mean what exactly does fill_value mean @Adelin

Comment: edit the question and clarify what you don't understand

Comment: have done that @Adelin